# mongorestore restored successfully, show databases not show the restored database centos 8 - mongodb 4.2

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, centos, mongorestore, centos8

I restored a database using this command
`mongorestore --dbpath = <my backup database path>`
and at the I got the : documents restored successfully

but when I use `show databases` in mongo, I see all of my databases except my restored databases.

I check this process for two different database but I have the same problem for twice of them.

The name of databases are all different.

Comment: You can list databases to find out which databases were restored.

Comment: If you already have databases, restore to an empty deployment.